# passing devise/warden session ID as params instead of via cookies/session

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, warden

I'm developing an API and I'd like to support authenticated user
sessions. Is it possible to pass the session information used by
devise/warden after a user has been authenticated? I know I can use
TokenAuthenticatable, but I assume the session ID is better because it
expires after some time, can be expired on a per session basis, and
I'd prefer to have a separate non-expirable auth token anyways.

I see that warden sets something like this:

> warden.user.user.key"=>["User", [4975], "Ejm5RbQhYVnNYFU7wX2o"]

Is it possible to simply refer to this in some form via GET or POST
params? Is this advisable?

Thanks

Comment: I would quite like to know this as well.